# Unstable AdS and cosmology theory

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, ads-cft

Now that the mathematician Georgios Moschidis has shown that an AdS universe is unstable, does this mean that our universe cannot be an AdS space, so all cosmological models that using an AdS structure are no longer to be considered? including the Maldacena AdS/CFT duality and String Theory on AdS?

Comment: We already know from observation that our universe isn't described (in cosmology at least) by AdS space, but dS instead. So the many problems related to string theory (and other theories who naturally lend themselves to having an AdS background) were there already, as far as I'm aware?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but our universe is currently considered flat, not $dS^n$

Comment: The exact shape is still a matter of debate in physical cosmology, but experimental data from various independent sources (WMAP, BOOMERanG, and Planck for example) confirm that the universe is flat with only a 0.4% margin of error.

Comment: Of course, I'm talking about the background vacuum: i.e. a universe with a positive cosmological constant, not a negative one. It's been a problem in string theory for decades trying to produce (meta-)stable, consistent dS vacua as opposed to AdS. You add your matter content on top of the background to get your usual cosmology stuff. The comments about the shape of the universe aren't strictly related to what I'm saying here. See the famous KKLT papers (and responses to them) for more details about this old problem.

Comment: It is already known that the AdS subspaces in holographic theories are not applicable to real life because we already know that the universe is not AdS. The usefulness of studying AdS/CFT is in exploring its inherent strong-weak duality, or in utilizing it to explore some other aspect of the spacetime and/or CFT. The study of dS solutions in string theory as a whole (dS = de Sitter, not a sphere element), and within possible dualities, is an ongoing area of research, and has faced more difficulties than finding AdS solutions. See: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0302219.pdf for starters.

Comment: There are cosmological models where the universe behaves like a AdS in the early universe and then becomes dS at some later time. I think the op is asking about the possiblity of this

Comment: @ Eletie and Zorawar - Thank you very much for your answers